# Why does *[checked] not match a single checked input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Lets say I have a checkbox with id 'test' and its on a page loaded with jQuery 1.5.2.

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox"/>
```

Now if I click on the checkbox to set it in the `checked` state...

Why does `$("#test").is(":checked")` return `true` and `$("#test").is("*[checked]")` return `false`.

Here's a [jsFiddle with the described scenario](http://jsfiddle.net/2QZvU/4/)

Comment: See follow on question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673570/why-does-checked-act-like-checked-when-using-jquerys-filter-method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`[checked]`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) is a selector that picks elements that are currently checked *with* the `checked` attribute not the property - in other words "if the element has the checked attribute, pick it up".

If you want to check if the checkbox is checked or not, you must use [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

Example usage:

```
if($('#test').is(':checked'))
{
   return true;
}
```

With jQuery 1.6 and higher you can use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function for performance reasons.

```
if($('#test').prop('checked'))
{
   return true;
}
```

Comment: This might be need to be another question, but they seem to be identical in this scenario : http://jsfiddle.net/2QZvU/9/

Answer (score 2):

Because `checked` isn't an attribute of an `input` element. It is a *property*. Your `*[checked]` selector checks to see if it has the `checked` attribute, which would never exist on an element. You can add the `checked="checked"` to an `input` element which sets the `checked` property of that object, but that attribute will always be there even when unchecking the box. This is because checking and unchecking only changes the `checked` property of the checkbox, not the `checked` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The checkedness of a checkbox is reflected in the object property `checked`. It can be set by the DOM attribute `checked`, but the direction is one-way: the DOM attribute does not get updated when the object's property changes. `:checked` is a dedicated pseudoselector which will check the object's property; `[checked]` is a selector which checks for the existence of the DOM attribute.

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion of the checked property on the jQuery property page:

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: The OP is using jQuery 1.5.2, not 1.6+.

Comment: Yes, and that page discusses both before and after 1.6

Comment: But it doesn't answer the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/2QZvU/5/

it must be *[:checked]

As Matt said checked is a property not an attribute