# Why does *[checked] act like :checked when using jQuery's filter method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673201/why-does-checked-not-match-a-single-checked-input-box).
Lets say I have two checkboxes on a page loaded with jQuery 1.5.2

```
<input id="test1" type="checkbox"/>
<input id="test2" type="checkbox"/>
```

Then lets click both of them to give each the `checked` property.
Now lets grab all checkboxes and filter out the ones that aren't checked

```
var numOfCheckedBoxes = $("input:checkbox").filter("*[checked]").size();
```

Now based on the answer to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673201/why-does-checked-not-match-a-single-checked-input-box), I would expect `numOfCheckedBoxes` to equal `0` but it equals `2`. I now I should just use `$("input:checkbox:checked")` or `$("input:checkbox").filter(":checked")`.

This differs from if I do

```
var numOfCheckedBoxes = $("#test1").filter("*[checked]").size();
```

which sets `numOfCheckedBoxes` equal to `0`.
Here is a jsFiddle of the [first scenario in question](http://jsfiddle.net/2QZvU/9/).
Here is a jsFiddle of the [second scenario in question](http://jsfiddle.net/2QZvU/13/).

Comment: this is looking a lot like a jQuery bug to me.

Comment: `$("input:checkbox").filter("*[checked]");` does not return the same results for me in chrome 16.0.912

Comment: @GregGuida, if you visit the jsFiddle and check both checkboxes the output isn't `2` for each? Because it is for me and I'm using 16.0.912.63

Comment: @Soldier.moth try this: change the fiddle (this one, not the other one) so that "inputs" is just `$('#test1')` ... that's what makes me think it's a bug.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah I noticed that as well, I'll try to edit my question to make that more clear

Comment: @Pointy I have to agree with you here. depending on the context that I use the filter in i'm getting different results

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that `jQuery.filter` explicitly checks to see whether the element list it's filtering has only one element in it. In that case, it calls `Sizzle.matchesSelector()`, but when there's more than one it calls `Sizzle.matches()`.  I bet ".is()" always uses `.matchesSelector`.

Comment: @Pointy, I think this may be Chrome-specific. Can anyone confirm in other browsers? This works just fine for me in IE8 on XP.

Comment: @jwiscarson Confirmed on firefox as well

Comment: [Here is another fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mgfxe/)

Comment: @Pointy, Deleted my answer because, well, I think you and the OP have a much better understanding of this than I could provide through testing. I confirmed this bug on FF 9 on XP as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in modern browsers, the DOM selection will be done with `querySelectorAll`.

This means that when doing DOM selection, `*[checked]` will actually look for that specific attribute.

When you do `':checked'` in DOM selection, you're using a `Sizzle` extension that is invalid CSS, so `querySelectorAll` is not used, and therefor `Sizzle` is used, and it looks at the property as well as the attribute.

---

So the difference here is that `.filter()` doesn't/can't use `querySelectorAll`, which means that you're going to get the proprietary behavior given by `Sizzle` instead of the valid DOM behavior.

---

It would be great if `Sizzle` was actually a compatibility patch for `querySelectorAll`, but it isn't, so you have to deal with the resulting inconsistencies.

---

**EDIT:**

It appears as though there's an optimization where if `filter()` is called against multiple elements, `Sizzle` is used, but if only one element, then `is()` is used.

This matters because `is()` will use `matchesSelector` in browsers that have it, and `matchesSelector` will give the same evaluation as `querySelectorAll`. That evaluation differs from `Sizzle`.

Comment: The thing is that I get different results from the fiddle on this question based on the initial selector used for the inputs. I don't think we're seeing correct behavior from jQuery here.

Comment: @Pointy: [With this example](http://jsfiddle.net/YehJ5/) I get the same behavior irrespective of whether the selector includes `:checked`. Does my example illustrate what you mean? If not, could you modify?

Comment: @amnotiam Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/YehJ5/1/ I updated your example to demonstrate the problem

Comment: @Soldier.moth: I'd bet that for some reason when a single match is found, there's an optimization where `is()` is used, and if multiple matches, `Sizzle`'s filter is used. The `is()` method will use the native `matchesSelector`, which is only available in very modern browsers, and will give a result similar to `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @Soldier.moth: Confirmed. [Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/YehJ5/3/) that uses `webkitMatchesSelector` instead of the filter, and you get the same behavior as the `.filter` that matches only one element.

Comment: @amnotiam Looks like its something like you described, there's a check in jquery's `filter` to call `Sizzle.matchesSelector()` if there's a single element and otherwise to call `Sizzle.matches()`

Comment: @Soldier.moth: I just updated my answer to reflect this information. And yeah, `Sizzle.matches` looks for a native `matchesSelector`, and uses it if available giving a proper CSS evaluation.

Comment: @amnotiam: Thanks for helping figure this one out

Answer (score 0):

`('[checked]')` checks for the existence of the `checked` attribute. It appears that browsers add/remove this attribute when the check-box has been checked/un-checked.

Comment: see my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673201/why-does-checked-not-match-a-single-checked-input-box as this does not appear to be the case

Comment: @Soldier.moth I tested with a few different browsers and `*[checked]` always returns the same results as `[checked]` for me.

Comment: @Jasper yes that's true but that's not quite what the issue is. The problem is that the way that selector behaves differs (sometimes) between the ".is()" method and the ".filter()" method.

Comment: @Jasper sorry for the confusion, see my edits, `*[checked]` & `:checked` differ if you start with one element.